# Displaying sitecore templates when hiding Item Bucket Content

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, buckets

One of the main purposes of Item Buckets is to contain a large repository of content items, without dealing with the normal structure in the content tree. With this said, displaying these **Hidden Items** would be unnecessary because they are auto-evaluated and placed in a folder structure that is formatted for you.

BUT I came across the problem where if **Hidden Items** in the **View** tab is unchecked, the Templates folder disappears.

Is there a setting either in the Bucket Item config or a base Sitecore setting that can be set to display Templates while using Item Buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue .. for now you will have to use the Template Manager to access templates. In the new version this issue is addressed and instead of using the 'Hidden' checkbox there is a separate 'Buckets' visibility tick box in the UI to control the hiding and showing of buckets.

Comment: Is there anywhere we can get visibility of these known issues? There seem to be quite a few bugs in this module? Also any idea when we can expect an update. The module's functionality is really promising, thanks!

Comment: I would also like to know when the new module will be coming out. I'm having quiet a few bugs regarding multiple item buckets.